# How to get hot module replacement working in webpack& gulp?

Tags: reactjs, gulp, webpack-dev-server

I have setup a gulp and webpack configuration for a reactjs app. This is a fragment of my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('webpack-dev-server', function(callback) {
    // modify some webpack config options
    var myConfig = Object.create(webpackConfig);
    myConfig.devtool = 'eval';
    myConfig.debug = true;
    myConfig.plugins = [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ];

    // Start a webpack-dev-server
    new WebpackDevServer(webpack(myConfig), {
        hot: true,
        stats: {
            colors: true
        }

    }).listen(9090, 'localhost', function(err) {
        if (err) throw new gulpUtil.PluginError('webpack-dev-server', err);
    });
});
```

This is my webpack.config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    entry: ['webpack/hot/dev-server', './src/app.js'],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/src/js',
        publicPath: '/src/',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

This is a link to the repo:https://github.com/dimitri-a/koekje

Answer (score 0):

For react hot loader to work you will need to add webpack-dev-server & react hot loader plugin

npm install react-hot-loader --save-dev

npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev

Add devServer config(contentBase is from where the files will be served) and add 'react-hot' in the loader before the 'babel-loader'

Finally you need to run webpack-dev-server with 2 options:
webpack-dev-server --hot --inline

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

/*
 * Default webpack configuration for development
 */
var config = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  cache: true,
  entry: ['webpack/hot/dev-server', './src/app.js'],
  output: {
      path: __dirname + '/src/js',
      publicPath: '/src/',
      filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'],
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015','react']
      }
    }]
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./src",
    colors: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true
  },
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: now I am getting: ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-hot,babel-loader' in /Users/dimitri/hmr/koekje
 @ multi main

Comment: and nothing is displaying

Comment: @bierhier For passing multiple loaders loader key will take array as input. loader: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader']